# GvrViewerMain rotates the camera yourself. Unity3D + Google VR

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, camera, angle, google-cardboard

I have a problem. Using Google VR + Unity. GameObject Camera automatically changes the angle "Y". The device does not change positions. Maybe fluctuations in the hands. The editor is no problem. The device Samsung S6.

Pic 0 sec
[image]

Pic after ~15 sec
[image]

```
public void Update() {
    text.text = cameraTransform.eulerAngles.y.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry mate but this is a known issue and it's been there since day 1. It's called camera drift. It lives in this beautiful ecosystem of github community where the developers keep closing/ignoring it and the users keep reopening/resubmitting.

https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/309